# Проверка привязки товара к определенной категории в Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, if

Как проверить вхождение товара в определенную категорию и вывести текст на странице товара при совпадении?

Например, товар входит в несколько категорий 1 и 3. Структура такая:

```
Категория 1
 - категория 2
 - категория 3
Категория 4
 - категория 5
и т.д.
```

Проверить текущую категорию не сложно:

```
if ( has_term( 'cat3', 'product_cat' ) ) {
       echo 'Категория 3';
}
```

А вот как проверть вхождение товара в категорию 1? То есть, создать условие:

Если товар входит в категорию 1, вывести одно, если в категорию 4 - другое. И так далее...

Спасибо за любую подсказку!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все совсем просто

```
if ( has_term( 'cat1', 'product_cat' ) ) {
    echo 'Категория 1';
} elseif ( has_term( 'cat4', 'product_cat' ) ) {
    echo 'Категория 4';
}
```

Comment: Странно, изначально я ставил ярлык родительской категории и ничего не работало, поэтому и вопрос написал. Подумал, что привязка идет только к конечной категории. Магия.